# How Many Arrows / Bolts Will Bless Weapon Affect?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells

The [spell description](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/b/bless-weapon) says ...

> Individual arrows or bolts can be transmuted, but affected projectile weapons (such as bows) don't confer the benefit to the projectiles they shoot.

... but doesn't say how many. There must be an upper limit and I'd hope this spell affects more than 1 arrow / bolt per casting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Individual" means one. Spells that affect more than one say so explicitly. For example, consider [*Greater Magic Weapon*](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/spells/magicWeapon.html#magic-weapon-greater)

> ...
>
> **Target:** one weapon or 50 projectiles (all of which must be together at the time of casting)
>
> ...
>
> This spell functions like magic weapon ... Alternatively, you can affect as many as 50 arrows, bolts, or bullets. The projectiles must be of the same kind, and they have to be together (in the same quiver or other container).
>
> ...

*Bless Weapon* doesn't have such language, so it only works on a single arrow or bolt.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I wish the language was clear and said "a single arrow or bolt". "Individual arrows" seems to imply more than 1.

Comment: @KornMuffin The language is accurate. “Individual arrows” = “Individual (object that is of the arrow type)”. English nouns of the “type” kind look the same as the “plural” kind but are not actually plural.

Comment: @Rawling I'm concerned that this has become a trivia tangent that isn't aimed at helping the post in any way. If you want more information on corner cases of English grammar, [english.se] can probably help. Ask about “categorical nouns”. Though check [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/5546/1613) first to avoid asking a duplicate.

Comment: Not sure if this should be a new question (I'm happy to create) but what is the value of casting this spell on a projectile weapon (other that affecting a single arrow/bolt)?

Comment: @KornMuffin That sounds like a new question, yeah.

Comment: @KornMuffin In case you want to use it as an improvised bludgeoning weapon. :)

Comment: @SPavel Ha ha ha ... I was thinking the same thing. I guess that's another question ... what is the damage when swinging a bow in melee? Does a paladin's smite apply? Thanks guys for spending the time to respond /debate!