# What Benefits Does Bless Weapon Confer To a Projectile Weapon?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells

The [spell description](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/spells/blessWeapon.html#bless-weapon) says (my bold emphasis) ...

> This transmutation makes a weapon strike true against evil foes. The weapon is treated as having a +1 enhancement bonus for the purpose of bypassing the DR of evil creatures or striking evil incorporeal creatures (though the spell doesn't grant an actual enhancement bonus). The weapon also becomes good-aligned, which means it can bypass the DR of certain creatures. (This effect overrides and suppresses any other alignment the weapon might have.) **Individual arrows or bolts can be transmuted, but affected projectile weapons (such as bows) don't confer the benefit to the projectiles they shoot.**
>
> In addition, all critical hit rolls against evil foes are automatically successful, so every threat is a critical hit. This last effect does not apply to any weapon that already has a magical effect related to critical hits, such as a keen weapon or a vorpal sword.

[This answer to the spell usage](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/77045/9220) indicates that the spell will only affect a single arrow/bolt.

My question is what are the exact benefits of casting Bless Weapon on a  projectile weapon (other than affecting a single arrow/bolt)? Does it only get the critical confirm effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It affects the single bolt or arrow exactly the same way it would affect a dagger or sword. But if you cast it on a bow instead of the arrow, the bow itself gains the benefits, not the arrows you shoot from it. Unless you intend to hit someone with the bow you're better off casting it on one arrow at a time.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Why would they put the part in bold in the middle of the description instead of the very end? That makes me believe that you should at least get the crit confirm bonus.

Comment: @KornMuffin the relevant part of your bolded section is probably "affected projectile weapons (such as bows) don't confer the benefit to the projectiles they shoot."

Answer (score -1):

It's seems like the consensus [here](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2tjb2?What-Benefits-Does-Bless-Weapon-Confer-To-a) is that when Bless Weapon is cast upon a projectile weapon, the critical confirmation benefit applies to each piece of ammo shot from it but the DR and weapon alignment benefits only apply when used as an improvised weapon.

If cast upon ammo it sounds like it would only affect a single piece of ammo.

Comment: Why the downvote? An explanation would be helpful and appreciated

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but I only see 4 people other than you involved in the linked thread and there doesn't seem to be agreement.  I personally think your answer is better without the linked thread which just shows people disagree:P

Answer (score -2):

If cast on, say a bow, it either:

1. Does nothing (effectively) unless you use your bow as a club.
   OR
2. Automatically confirms critical threats against evil foes on attacks performed with the bow (melee or ranged).

The REAL answer as to which it does, is: ask the DM.  They decide.

(Or just decide for yourself and see if they interrupt and decide otherwise).